# Placement of javascript in rails layout

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, layout, asset-pipeline

I have some jquery plugins that are required in the header.

For page performance it would be better to have my js at the bottom of the page. Is there a way I can make javascript load in the header of some pages and in the footer of others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is yes, you can place the javascript load code at the base of your template, which helps with some load performance.

Place this line `<%= javascript_include_tag "application"  %>` at the end of the body

I can't think of a good reason to load it in the header for some and the footer for others.

Comment: Because I am using a jquery plugin which requires that it's jquery code is loaded before the element for the plugin. Hence if I load my js in the footer the plugin doesn't work.

Comment: You can happily specify the load order using the require's in your `application.js`

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that the `asset-pipeline` tag also means "I'm precompiling assets and need to generate something besides application.*"

From: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

If you have other manifests or individual stylesheets and JavaScript files to include, you can add them to the `precompile` array in `config/application.rb`:

```
config.assets.precompile += ['admin.js', 'admin.css', 'swfObject.js']
```

---

A file such as `admin.js` should not require assets which overlap with other precompiled files which are loaded on a page. So long as that is the case, I believe this will solve the problem you are encountering with trying to have includes in your footer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

in the bottom of your html structure to load `ALL` js files in the bottom of your page.

You can also create another js file (`jsheader.js`, for example) with other requires and do the same thing:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "jsheader" %>
```

and create another file (`jsfooter.js`, for example), and add it to the bottom:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "jsfooter" %>
```

Now you will have in the `header` all the scripts that you need, same thing for your `footer` scripts.